# Встраивание тела функции в месте её вызова без inline

Tags: c

На ум приходит только что-то типа шаблонизации через #define, но не хватает соображений, как это сделать красиво.

Например, функцию такого вида:

```
int tempfunc(char *str1,int x) {
 ...
 ...
 ...
 return res;
}
```

Если её вызвать два раза:

```
tempfunc("str1",1);
tempfunc("str2",2);
```

а затем посмотреть дизассемблером, то мы увидим, что физически существует один эекземпляр tempfunc по адресу, допустим 0x100500, а вызов - это просто предзагрузка аргументов в регистры и джамп по этому адресу.

Мне же требуется сделать так, чтобы компилятор дублировал каждый вызов этой функции в машинном коде исполняемого файла, чтобы фукнция физически вызывалась из разных участков памяти.

Проблема в том, что я не могу придумать, как это сделать без code smell и так, чтобы гарантированно компилятор не оптимизировал именно этот момент.

Comment: хотелось бы больше конкретики. какую функцию?

Comment: у define свои особенности - это просто "встраиваемый код". Простейшую ф-цию покажу (без циклов и т п.), а лучше приведите исходный код ф-ции. Простейший пример `#define F1(x) (x*x+5)` Но более сложные выражения задать через define сложнее.

Comment: @nick_n_a, не забывайте `x` внутри выражения обернуть скобками

Comment: Думаю, что define стоит воспринимать как механизм "сокращений", а не как функцию, т.е. если у вас есть куски кода, которые повторяются - то их можно "сократить" используя define более эфективно, чем через функцию. (хотя define не очень приветствуется, т.к. запутывает код)

Comment: Добавил конкретики в пост.

Comment: А можно подробнее? Зачем вы хотите это сделать? Для оптимизации? Почему без `inline` (хотя он сам по себе не гарантирует встраивание, но есть же всякие `__attribute__((always_inline))` и `__forceinline`)? Что конкретно не получилось сделать с `#define`?

Comment: Нет, троеточие тут не годится. Полностью текст функции. Не всё можно "запихнуть" в define. Потому что define не функция, а "сокращение".

Comment: это типа `atoi`?

Answer (score 2):

```
# define TEMPFUNC(S,I,R) \
{ char *TEMPstr1=S; \
  int TEMPx=I; \
  int TEMPresult; \
  ... \
  R = TEMPresult ; }

int r1;
int r2;
TEMPFUNC("str1",1,r1);
TEMPFUNC("str2",2,r2);
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно!